# Why it won't detect onTouch?

Tags: android

My ActionBar will be called by pressing "Menu button" like this. and it's working fine

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
    if (mActionBar.isShowing()) {
        mActionBar.hide();
    }
    else {
        mActionBar.show();
    }
}else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    WebView  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.goBack();
}
return true;
}
```

When a user touches screen while ActionBar is shown, ActionBar should disappear.
But it won't detect onTouch event.  Why?

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mActionBar.isShowing()) {
                mActionBar.hide();
            }
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (mActionBar.isShowing()) {
                mActionBar.hide();
            }
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }

};
```

it still won't work:(

Comment: did you set the listener?

Comment: setOnTouchListener(this);

Comment: @MarciCăşvan I added updated. Please see it

Comment: When I want to use a touchlistener and is not triggered by default, then I want to set a listener on the view I am touching. You will have to figure out what your view that you are clicking on is

Comment: you just created it but not set it on a view

Comment: @MarciCăşvan I'd like to assign to myWebView

Comment: For me it disappears automatically while I touch the screen. I am using [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) provided by Google.

Comment: @Gunaseelan what version do you use?

Comment: Are there any other views overlapping you webview? please set the listener to those views too, may be the overlapping views gains the onTouch event before your webview does. Hope this helps

Comment: You are welcome friend

Answer (score 0):

Change the return value as false

```
 return false;
```

Comment: Nah, it didn't do anything.